# How to find specific word on <a>tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```xml
<li>                                                
    <a href="/3137?category=957259">"this word"</a>
    <span class="date">11:08:57</span>
</li>
```

When using `beautifulsoup` in Python, how to pick "this word" sentence?

result = li.a.string I tried but it does not work.

I want to see result like this "this work" help me out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `find()` function and passing a css selector there, then grabbing the text from that using the `.text`

```
desired_text = soup.find('a[href="/3137?category=957259"]').text
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but '.text' does not work.
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' also 'string'

Comment: found it. 
desired_text = li.a.text 
it did work well.